# How to convert variable to double (KeyValue) in KeyDown in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, variables, keydown, playsound

I have this code:

```
Private Sub key(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        If FuSt = False Then
            FuSt = True
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Settings.Full)
        Else
            FuSt = False
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(DIRECOTRY)
        End If
    End If
    If e.KeyValue = b1 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(SoundsDir & "1.wav")
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I want to play b1 (Z button on the keyboard) I have this error:

> Conversation from "z" to Double is incorrect (Somethink like that)

Can you help me?

Comment: Mixing strings and enums in a comparison is not a good idea.  Instead use the KeyPress event to detect typing keys like "z".

Comment: Replace `b1` with `Keys.Z`?

Answer (score 0):

To assign keys to a variable b1 try as said below.

`Keys` is an enum.

```
Dim b1 As Keys
b1 = Keys.Z
```

Like  **Hans Passant** comment, if you want to use `KeyPress` event (recommended), try below code.

```
   Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Char.ToLower(ChrW(Keys.Z)) Then
            MsgBox("Z selecetd")
        End If
    End Sub
```

or if you want to go with `KeyDown` event, try below code.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Z) Then
        MsgBox("Z selecetd")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ya, I Know, but i want to the Keys.z is in variable b1

Comment: Updated the answer. you can try it.